# How do I repeat an NLA strip at the same speed it was before it was an NLA strip?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

As the title says, I'd like to be able to repeat my animation at the speed it's currently at when I convert it into an NLA strip.

Comment: When you push an action onto an NLA strip, the speed of the action doesn't change, so I don't know what you mean by "speed it's current at".  However, if you simply want to repeat the action, you can set a repeat value in the NLA strip N panel.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Have you changed the speed of the strip? Go into the N panel > Strip > Action Clip > Playback Scale

Comment: I tried doing what moonboots said, but when I go to action clip and increase playback scale the animation slows down. I should mention this is a looping animation.